# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get a query set which contains post based on usernames which are stored in model "FollowingProfiles". so models and corresponding views is as follows:-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    Follwers=models.IntegerField(default='0')
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    bio=models.TextField(max_length=120,blank=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    birth_date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ProfilePic=models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatar',blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

class FollowingProfiles(models.Model):
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ProfileName=models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfileName

class post(models.Model):
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='PostMedia',blank=True,null=True)
    DatePosted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Content=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Profile.user.username
```

## views.py

```
def feed(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        userprofile=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile__user=request.user)
        for p in userprofile:
            postuser=post.objects.filter(Profile__user__username=p.ProfileName)
            usrpost+=postuser
        return render(request,'feed/feed.html',{'usrpost':usrpost})
    else:
        return redirect('signup')
```

It produces following error:-

```
function' object has no attribute 'objects'
C:\Users\G COMTECH SYSTEM\django-projects\saporaapp\sapora\views.py in feed, line 45
line 45 is 
     postuser=post.objects.filter(Profile__user__username=p.ProfileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `post` model is conflicting with some `post` declared as function. 
What I suggest is to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in naming your Classes, function, variables and so on in order to avoid such cases.

In your particular case I would rename `post` model into `Post` as it's better to name Classes in CamelCase style.
But for fields your are using CamelCase, but it's better to use underscore:
Like that:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='PostMedia',blank=True,null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

If you want to make it work fast find where `post` can be declared as a function in `view.py` file and rename it. If it's something imported you can change `from mymodule import post` to be `import mymodule` and then call function as `mymodule.post`

Also `usrpost` is not declared and here is a better solution without `for` loop:

```
userprofile_names=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile__user=request.user).values_list('ProfileName', flat=True)
usrpost=post.objects.filter(Profile__user__username__in=userprofile_names)
return render(request,'feed/feed.html',{'usrpost':usrpost})
```

Comment: Now i am getting unboundlocalerror at usrpost referenced before assignment

Comment: Now i am getting unboundlocalerror at usrpost referenced before assignment

Comment: It's because you use `usrpost` before assignment. What is `usrpost` is it supposed to be a list?

Comment: Just declare `usrpost = ` before your `for p in userprofile` loop.

Comment: Then can i declare usrpost=null earlier??

Comment: Its better to do without `for` loop. Change it according to my edited answer.